# SQL Queue to get workload in 2 weeks [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, prediction

Currently, the queue shows me the workload of products in a oven and for product which are in the oven too, but actually for some hours in a test outside of the oven.

I count the h with "gesamt" for each product -> this show me how Long they stay already in the oven. Mostly the products stay 1000h in the oven its defined in "Zielgröße" in the db.

What I want is that the queue should show me the workload of the oven for the next 2 weeks as a prediction (336h). Thats all "gesamt" which is over "Zielgröße" (mostly 1000) not shown in the queue maybe handled in a temporary table or whatever.

Is it possible to handle this in Micrososft SQL Server?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT TesterID,Name, TesterNr, COUNT(Name) as Anzahl, gesamt  FROM 
(SELECT AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID, 
                                Bezeichnung, 
                                AnzModule, 
                                Tester.Name, TesterNr, 
                                Testname,
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TestaufstellungID, 
                                lastRO, 
                                gesamt, 
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.Einheit, 
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.PlanID,
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TesterID
                        FROM DB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben inner join
                        DB.dbo.v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend on 
                        AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID = v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.QualiID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Tester on  
                        Tester.TesterID = v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TesterID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testaufstellung on  
                        Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID = v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TestaufstellungID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testnamen on Testnamen.TestnameID = Testaufstellung.TestnameID
                        Where Tester.Name = 'KPS02'
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID, 
                        Bezeichnung, AnzModule, Tester.Name, TesterNr, 
                        Testname,
                        Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.gesamt as lastRO, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.gesamt, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.Einheit, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.PlanID, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.TesterID
                FROM    DB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben inner join
                        DB.dbo.v_gesamtBerechnung on 
                        AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID = v_gesamtBerechnung.QualiID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Tester on  
                        Tester.TesterID = v_gesamtBerechnung.TesterID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testaufstellung on  
                        Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID = v_gesamtBerechnung.TestaufstellungID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testnamen on Testnamen.TestnameID = Testaufstellung.TestnameID
                        WHERE Testaufstellung.fertig ='0'
                        AND Testaufstellung.aktiv ='1'
                        AND Testaufstellung.Zielgröße > v_gesamtBerechnung.gesamt
                        AND Tester.Name = 'KPS02'
                        AND v_gesamtBerechnung.TestaufstellungID not in (Select TestaufstellungID from DB.dbo.v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend)) x
                        group by TesterID, Name, TesterNr, gesamt
```

Here the table to show in an example what I want

actual workload

```
          TesterID       Name    TesterNr   Anzahl      gesamt
          -------------- ------- ---------- ----------- -----------
Product1    8              KPS02   2          1           209
Product2    8              KPS02   2          1           216
Product3    8              KPS02   2          1           816
Product4    8              KPS02   2          1           835
```

workload in 2 weeks

```
         TesterID       Name    TesterNr   Anzahl      gesamt
         -------------- ------- ---------- ----------- -----------
Product1        8              KPS02   2          1           545
Product2        8              KPS02   2          1           552
```

the last recors are over 1000 Zielgröße, so just dont show them in the prediction queue

```
Product3    8              KPS02   2          1           1152
Product4    8              KPS02   2          1           1171
```

I hope you guys can follow me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I edited the code. Just for me who works with SQL alongside is the ansi 89 better to understand.

Comment: So 'Actual Workload' above is what's currently going on now, and 'workload in 2 weaks' is where the oven will be in 2 weeks if nothing else goes into it, is that correct? So the first 2 records are gone as 209 - 336 < 0 so it's complete as well as 216 - 336 < 0, so also complete. The other two records have hours left, is that anywhere near correct?

Comment: nope workload in 2 weeks is where the individual product test is in "gesamt" hours not the oven. the oven is everytime on. I edited the table for clearness. Atm now i have 4 products in the oven, but i want to show me how many products in two weeks are in the oven. It should be show me only 2 products becasue 2 of them will be more than 1000h in the oven in 2 weeks so. I want a workload planing overview for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll edit this answer until it's solved, but here's my first attempt:

```
SELECT TesterID,Name, TesterNr, COUNT(Name) as Anzahl, gesamt + 336 as gesamt
FROM 
(SELECT AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID, 
                                Bezeichnung, 
                                AnzModule, 
                                Tester.Name, TesterNr, 
                                Testname,
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TestaufstellungID, 
                                lastRO, 
                                gesamt, 
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.Einheit, 
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.PlanID,
                                v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TesterID
                        FROM DB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben inner join
                        DB.dbo.v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend on 
                        AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID = v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.QualiID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Tester on  
                        Tester.TesterID = v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TesterID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testaufstellung on  
                        Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID = v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend.TestaufstellungID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testnamen on Testnamen.TestnameID = Testaufstellung.TestnameID
                        Where Tester.Name = 'KPS02'
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID, 
                        Bezeichnung, AnzModule, Tester.Name, TesterNr, 
                        Testname,
                        Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.gesamt as lastRO, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.gesamt, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.Einheit, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.PlanID, 
                        v_gesamtBerechnung.TesterID
                FROM    DB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben inner join
                        DB.dbo.v_gesamtBerechnung on 
                        AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID = v_gesamtBerechnung.QualiID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Tester on  
                        Tester.TesterID = v_gesamtBerechnung.TesterID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testaufstellung on  
                        Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID = v_gesamtBerechnung.TestaufstellungID inner join
                        DB.dbo.Testnamen on Testnamen.TestnameID = Testaufstellung.TestnameID
                        WHERE Testaufstellung.fertig ='0'
                        AND Testaufstellung.aktiv ='1'
                        AND Testaufstellung.Zielgröße > v_gesamtBerechnung.gesamt
                        AND Tester.Name = 'KPS02'
                        AND v_gesamtBerechnung.TestaufstellungID not in (Select TestaufstellungID from DB.dbo.v_gesamtBerechnungLaufend)) x
                        group by TesterID, Name, TesterNr, gesamt
) A
WHERE gesamt + 336 < 1000
```

It seems to me like all you need to do is add 336 to the current values and then filter out anything less than 1000.